# Nested forms rails field does not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am trying to do nested forms like mentioned here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

The goal is as follows: I have multiple colli with one checkbox which can be checked. The colli list can be deleted or modified but the checks and their information need to stay.

**Model**

```
class Colli < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :check, foreign_key: "subcontainerid", primary_key: "colliid"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :check, allow_destroy: true
end

class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :colli
end
```

So every colli has one check. The colliid from the colli table created a link with the check table using the subcontainer id.

**Controller**

Within the colli controller I whitelist the check_attributes.

```
def colli_params
  params.require(:colli).permit(:colliid, :collinaam, check_attributes: [:id, :checked])
end
```

**Form**

My form looks like this.

```
<%= form_for(@colli) do |f| %>
  <% if @colli.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@colli.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this colli from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @colli.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :checks do |checks_f| %>
  <p>check start</p>
  <div class="field">
    <%= checks_f.label :checked %><br>
    <%= checks_f.check_box :checked %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :colliid %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :colliid %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :collinaam %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :collinaam %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

If I do form_for :check I can't see the checkboxes. When I do form_for :checks I see a checkbox but it does not work. When clicking submit I see following error:

```
undefined method `checked' for nil:NilClass

<p>
  <strong>Checked:</strong>
  <%= @colli.check.checked %>
</p><p>
  <strong>Collinaam:</strong>
  <%= @colli.collinaam %>
```

Which means it did not get saved. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your form-

```
<%= f.fields_for :checks, @colli.check.build do |checks_f| %>
 <p>check start</p>
 <div class="field">
  <%= checks_f.label :checked %><br>
  <%= checks_f.check_box :checked %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This does not work `undefined method build for nil:NilClass` but if I do a `@colli.build_check` in the edit action from the controller it does work.